# How to read a json file in java?

Tags: java, json

I'm trying to read in this json data from a file

```
[{"name":"Luke","score":50},{"name":"Ryan","score":70}]
```

Code:

```
JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();

try{

Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("C:/Users/user/Documents/HighscoresJSON.json"));
JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;

String usersName = (String) jsonObject.get("name");
System.out.println("Name of user: " + usersName);

int usersScore = (int) jsonObject.get("score");
System.out.println("Score: " + usersScore);
```

This gives me the error:

```
com.google.gson.JsonArray cannot be cast to org.json.JSONObject
```

Answer (score 5):

There are a couple problems:

1. Your JSON is obviously an array (the `[` and `]` wrapping it give it away) and you are trying to treat it as a JSON object.
2. You're mixing two different JSON libraries - Gson and the org.json library.

Stick to one library (Gson in this case):

```
Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("something.json"));
JsonArray jsonArray = (JsonArray) obj;

for (JsonElement element : jsonArray) {
    JsonObject jsonObject = element.getAsJsonObject();

    String usersName = jsonObject.get("name").getAsString();
    System.out.println("Name of user: " + usersName);

    int usersScore = jsonObject.get("score").getAsInt();
    System.out.println("Score: " + usersScore);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, very helpful, only issue is I get an error under jsonArray in the loop that says Can only iterate over an array or an instance of java.lang.Iterable